# How to fill class properties from model Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an Class `Car` with some properties:

```
public id: number;
public roleId: number;
public roleName: string;
```

Also I have the same object `{id: 1, roleId: 1, roleName: 4}`

How to assign this object to each property?

I dont want to use:

```
this.id = obj.id;
this.roleName = obj.roleName;
this.roleId = obj.roleId;
```

Comment: Consider this: [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Comment: It works witj simple objects, not with properties of class

Comment: Corresbonding to object.assign. What about destructing. { ...obj, this.id, this.roleName, this.roleId }

Comment: type of `roleName` is string, so in your object the value of `roleName` should also be a string, then just use assignment ( = ) operator. Otherwise, change your `roleName` type to any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use object.assign property.

```
Object.assign(new Car(), {
        id: obj.id,
        roleName : obj.roleName,
        roleId : obj.roleId
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax:

```
class Car {
    public id?: number;
    public roleId?: number;
    public roleName?: string;

    constructor(values: Car) {
      Object.assign(this, values);
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
 let car = new Car({id: 1, roleId: 1, roleName: "4"});
```

**[Demo StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ecu87k?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

**[DEMO plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/a5cO9e0x9PPfE7YKNt0R?p=preview)**

Comment: FYI - The demo is working in Chrome and FireFox, but Edge, IE11  shows fatal error.

Comment: Added plunker demo

Comment: Stackblitz is new, maybe there is a small bug :)